# Service to interface with sessions table?

Tags: 8, sessions

In my module, I need greater session control, beyond simple max_lifetime and other parameters taken from PHP config. What I did was to add a column to the `sessions` table that gives me the effective session expiration, which I can compare against to know if to revoke the session. (I also want to "cache" this in the local session, but this is unrelated to the question).

The question is, what is the best way to retrieve the new data from the `sessions` table? I can just send a direct DB query, such as:

```
Database::getConnection()->query('SELECT expires_at FROM {sessions} s WHERE s.uid = :uid', [':uid' => $uid]);
```

However, is there a built-in service for accessing this table, for greater abstraction?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`Dynamic Queries`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/introduction-to-dynamic-queries)
instead of `Database::getConnection()->query('SELECT expires_at FROM {sessions} s WHERE s.uid = :uid', [':uid' => $uid]);`

You can do:

```
  // Create an object of type Select.
  $database = \Drupal::database();
  $query = $database->select('sessions', 's');
  // Add extra detail to this query object: a condition, fields and a range.
  $query->condition('s.uid', $uid, '=');
  $query->fields('s', ['expires_at']);
  $result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I assume this means that there is no built-in service I can use specifically for the sessions table?

Comment: No i don't think so, as far as i now there is only **Database abstraction layer** you can check it here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/group/database/8.2.x